# GET Request is not working once subdomain is enabled in Nginx

Tags: nginx, https, url-rewriting, get

By enabling sub domain to my public IP am not getting the GET respone from my backend.

In my local machine once i type the URL http://localhost:3001/objects?design=ficco-desings&category=formals&type=

We are getting the respone in JSON [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xDHi.png). In my local machine it is working as expected.

Once we deployed in production(AWS), we configured subdomain as api.inzack.com in Nginx [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJB9u.png)

The error we are getting is [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jPVF.png)

We are using rewrite tag in Nginx conf file to send the GET request parameters.

pls suggest where am making the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/objects/ {
  proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3001/$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: i tried with above step same issue is persisting.. pls suggest the way forward

Comment: Its working now.... earlier was pointing to wrong IP